# Assalamu Walaikum.. I want to ask if is it haram to upload a cartoon girl with a hijab as my profile picture

Tags: hijab

Is it haram to upload a cartoon girl with a hijab as my profile picture?[image: search wallpaper Hijab Cartoon Dp, girl cartoon hijab HD phone]

Comment: If you think it would be haram to use it as your profile picture how didn't you think it would be haram to post the picture in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Refrain from using pictures with animate objects, rather use a picture of some scenery etc.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no haram activities, images and dolls are allowed in Islam. You can see Aysha (r.a), when married to prophet (s.a) used to play with dolls. Using the analogy, there is no wrong in using cartoon characters as profile picture

> "The Messenger of Allah married me when I was six, and consummated the
> marriage with me when I was nine, and I used to play with dolls." https://sunnah.com/nasai:3378

Comment: What does consummate mean?